# Name of this Block?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, footer

What is the name of this block in Magento 1.9.2 using the RWD theme.
[image]
Already removed the other footer blocks like -

```
<remove name="footer_links"/>
<remove name="footer_links2"/>
```

footer_links3 doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Block name** is `cms_footer_links`.

Which calling ***a cms static block***  `footer_links_company`

Check at [`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/cms.xml`](https://github.com/engineyard/magento-ce-1.9/blob/master/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/cms.xml#L35)

Comment: Aha 40 sec late :)

Answer (score 3):

this is a cms block in rwd theme go to below file you will get this cms block
`app/design/frontend/red/default/page/html/footer.phtml`

and if you want to disable from admin then go to login admin  `cms->static Block` find identifier as `footer_links_company` and disable that cms block

Answer (score 1):

For the future, if you want to figure this out yourself, enable template hinting in the admin panel: system -> developer. Then append your URL with ?ath=1 and you can see where the block exactly comes from.

Comment: The ath parameter belongs to AOE TemplateHints, it's not part of core Magento :-)

Comment: Oh, really? I thought Magento did have some basic template hinting functionality. Since it's in our standard package I wouldn't know otherwise, thanks!

Comment: Grangar, yes magento does have built in template hinting, that module just extends it